# Laravel API cURL Request to Python

Tags: php, python, api, curl, laravel

I followed this Laravel token API tutorial: http://rjv.im/post/95988160186/api-token-authentication-with-laravel-and-sentry-part. I have written the following cURL request to communicate with my API:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token:tokenhere" http://localhost:8000/account
```

The request works properly, and accurately returns the expected data. When I translate this to Python I receive `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8000/account')
req.add_header("X-Auth-Token", "tokenhere")
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
print content
```

If I pass user credentials using basic auth instead of an X-Auth-Token, the request works as expected:

```
import urllib2

def basic_authorization(user, password):
    s = user + ":" + password
    return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

req = urllib2.Request("http://localhost:8000/account", headers = { "Authorization": basic_authorization("usernameHere", "passwordHere"), })

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print f.read()
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, how are you parsing the `X-Auth-Token` header on the server side? Because normally, headers are sent with a space after the colon—that's how `curl` is going to send all the rest of your headers, and how `urllib2` is going to send _all_ of the headers, including the one you added. If your server is actually expecting `'X-Auth-Token:tokenhere'` and rejecting `'X-Auth-Token: tokenhere'`, that's a bug that you need to fix on the server side.

Comment: Second, in order to debug this, you need to first look at what you're sending that's different. Can you get your server to log the complete request so you can compare them? Or view them in Wireshark? Or just run something like `nc -kl 8000` instead of your server, and watch what it prints out when your `curl` command and Python program try to talk to it?

Comment: Finally, most auth-token mechanisms have a TTL/expiration/etc. Does the `curl` command work even right after the Python script failed, or did it just work in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something you missed in the tutorial. In the tokens table there is a column:

`$table->string('client');`

It is important from which client you are sending your request. I am using https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect to detect from which client I got the request.

But for now I will just try to see User Agent. In my laravel code I just logged every request to see what's happening with the following code:

```
Route::filter('auth.token', function($route, $request)
{
....

  Log::info($request);

....
}
```

Now, Let's see:

When I use curl from command line:

```
curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET http://localhost:8000/account
```

My User Agent is

```
User-Agent:   curl/7.32.0
```

I sent the same from python using your code above, User Agent is:

```
User-Agent:      Python-urllib/2.7
```

Ah! That must be it. You have to authenticate your user at least once using Basic Auth, it will give you a token and that token is valid for only that client. In the first part http://rjv.im/post/78940780589/api-token-authentication-with-laravel-and-sentry-part of tutorial there was no such condition. In the comments I received someone posted a query on how to support multiple clients, so this example was made to solve that problem.

Apart from that, may I suggest this library: https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard It supports Rate Limiting, easy to integrate with Sentry. It's a bit different from my tutorial. Using my solution you can hit any endpoint using Basic Auth or Token. Using above library, only token is permitted, so there is dedicated route to generate token. Let me know how it goes.